# 10 digit Regex Validation with angularJs ng-Pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, ng-pattern

I want one of my input fields to have exactly 10 digits. I have used `ng-pattern` in following manner

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/" ng-model="user.Identity" name="identity">
```

The problem is that this expression is allowing the user to enter numeric strings having more than 10 digits whereas, I want to allow exactly 10 digits. Is there a problem with my regex or my understanding of `ng-pattern`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` anchor indicates start of string/line as `$` does for the end, `^expr$` prevents the shifting window matches you see:

```
/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}$/
```

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid Additionaly to your answer. The `{1}` is redundant and you can get rid of it